# KeyPairGenerator - same key pair on different devices?

Tags: android, cryptography

Experts,

is it possible to use the Android KeyPairGenerator class to generate the same key pair on different devices? For example, by overwriting the SecureRandom class to generate the same shared secret.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of `SecureRandom`?

Comment: No. What you can do is agree on a key either via out-of-band communication of a key agreement protocol then use the key either directly or in a PRNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You *can* actually implement `SecureRandom` yourself as it has a public constructor. If you *should* do it is a different matter. It may well be that the key generator changes between versions, which means that you could re-create the wrong key. Furthermore - depending on the generation algorithm - the generation can take a long time. RSA key generation both has multiple ways of generating key pairs *and* is very slow.

In general you need to *seed* the RNG and keep that seed secret. That means that you have a value that requires the same kind of security as a secret key. In that case you might as well use that secret key to encrypt (or wrap) the private key and use it to distribute the key. If you use something like Elliptic Curve keys then the EC key is only double the size of the required seed size (if you do not encode the domain parameters but just the secret value s). So storing the private key doesn't take that many bytes.

If you want to use a seed to generate the key pair then you are better off using a well defined Key Derivation Function such as HKDF. Note that an EC private key is relatively easy to generate, so you might want to target that particular algorithm with a preset set of domain parameters (for example P-256). Basically you will have to do the key pair generation yourself - for instance by copying the key pair generation code - to make sure that the algorithm doesn't change.

Simply seeding an existing random number generator is a terribly bad idea. Now not just the key pair generator may change, but the random number generator as well. And it actually *has changed* on Android, a couple of times. And seeding it may still lead to different bytes as it may use truly random bytes *in addition* to the seed you feed it; this has *also* happened.

---

If you want to store nothing and use a password then use Elliptic Curves, deriving the private key using PBKDF2 with a hash of the same size as the Elliptic Curve. If you can store something use a Password Based Key Derivation Function such as PBKDF2 and encrypt the private key instead, possibly using PKCS#12 key store or PGP.